# Error extruding gmsh surfaces to abutting volumes

Tags: python, cad, gmsh

My application deals with many shapes processed with [gmsh's Python API](https://gitlab.onelab.info/gmsh/gmsh/blob/gmsh_4_10_5/api/gmsh.py), but I have reduced my problem to a MWE of two polygons which lie in separate planes. Their coordinates are:

```
# polygon spans (x, y, zs[0])
xy1 = [(0.0, 504.0), (247.0, 504.0), (247.0, 496.0), (0.0, 496.0), (0.0, 504.0)]
zs1 = [0, 50]

xy2 = [(0.0, 396.0), (0.0, 496.0), (0.0, 504.0), (247.0, 504.0), (285.0, 504.0), (285.0, 496.0), (285.0, 396.0), (285.0, 388.0), (247.0, 388.0), (0.0, 388.0), (0.0, 396.0)]
zs2 = [50, 100]
```

My first step is to project these coordinates onto a finite grid so gmsh doesn't complain about node duplication. I do this by merging proximate points, although this isn't necessary for the example above so I simplify it here for clarity:

```py
coord_labels = {}

def get_coord_label(xyz):
    if xyz not in coord_labels:
        coord_labels[xyz] = gmsh.model.geo.add_point(*xyz)
    return coord_labels[xyz]

pts1 = [get_coord_label((x,y,zs1[0])) for (x,y) in xy1]
pts2 = [get_coord_label((x,y,zs2[0])) for (x,y) in xy2]
```

This produces unique gmsh point labels:

```py
pts1
>>> [1, 2, 3, 4, 1]

pts2
>>> [5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 5]
```

My task now is to extrude these polygons into polyhedra which span `zs[0]` to `zs[1]`. Since the polygons are specified in the `z = zs[0]` plane, I extrude them along vector `(0,0,1)` by a distance `zs[1]-zs[0]` like so:

```
def extrude(pts, dz):
    lines = [gmsh.model.geo.add_line(pts[i], pts[i+1]) for i in range(len(pts)-1)]
    face = gmsh.model.geo.add_plane_surface([gmsh.model.geo.add_curve_loop(lines, reorient=True)])
    objs = gmsh.model.geo.extrude([(2,face)], 0,0, dz)

extrude(pts1, zs1[1] - zs1[0])
extrude(pts2, zs2[1] - zs2[0])
```

The resulting polyhedra look fine to me when I run

```
gmsh.model.geo.synchronize()
gmsh.fltk.run()
```

> [image]

Above, we see the two volumes; the lower bottom-right one is formed by `xy1` and shares its top-surface at `z=50` with a sub-bottom-surface of `xy2`'s extrusion.

Alas, this geometry cannot be meshed. Calling

```
gmsh.model.mesh.generate()
```

raises exception

```
No elements in volume 1
```

If I had to guess, the problem is that gmsh's `extrusion` function (of `xy1`) is creating new points within surface `z = zs1[1]`, and are not automatically recognised co-planar with `z = zs2[0]`. But this is my speculation, and I am not sure why it causes this issue nor how to workaround it.

The entire process (e.g. having to myself group proximate coordinates before extrusion) seems unreasonably difficult for such a simple exercise of extruding polygons! What am I doing wrong? Note in my application, *some* abutting volumes like this should be merged into a single volume in the mesh, while others should be treated separately (and ergo have an explicit separating surface).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the occ kernel instead of the geo kernel (replace all occurences of "geo" by "occ", and take care with a few function names and arguments). With this change gmsh will mesh both volumes. However the will be meshed seperately because they are not connected in any way. To connect them you need to use the

```
gmsh.model.occ.fragment(...)
```

function.

Here is the code:

```
import gmsh

gmsh.initialize()

# polygon spans (x, y, zs[0])
xy1 = [(0.0, 504.0), (247.0, 504.0), (247.0, 496.0), (0.0, 496.0), (0.0, 504.0)]
zs1 = [0, 50]

xy2 = [(0.0, 396.0), (0.0, 496.0), (0.0, 504.0), (247.0, 504.0), (285.0, 504.0), (285.0, 496.0), (285.0, 396.0), (285.0, 388.0), (247.0, 388.0), (0.0, 388.0), (0.0, 396.0)]
zs2 = [50, 100]

coord_labels = {}

def get_coord_label(xyz):
    if xyz not in coord_labels:
        coord_labels[xyz] = gmsh.model.occ.add_point(*xyz)
    return coord_labels[xyz]


pts1 = [get_coord_label((x,y,zs1[0])) for (x,y) in xy1]
pts2 = [get_coord_label((x,y,zs2[0])) for (x,y) in xy2]
gmsh.model.occ.synchronize()

def extrude(pts, dz):
    lines = [gmsh.model.occ.add_line(pts[i], pts[i+1]) for i in range(len(pts)-1)]
    loop = gmsh.model.occ.addCurveLoop(lines)
    face = gmsh.model.occ.addPlaneSurface([loop])
    objs = gmsh.model.occ.extrude([(2,face)], 0,0, dz)

extrude(pts1, zs1[1] - zs1[0])
extrude(pts2, zs2[1] - zs2[0])
gmsh.model.occ.synchronize()

volTags = gmsh.model.getEntities(3)
gmsh.model.occ.fragment([volTags[0]], [volTags[1]])
gmsh.model.occ.synchronize()
gmsh.model.mesh.generate()
gmsh.fltk.run()
gmsh.finalize()
```

You should try out commenting the line

```
gmsh.model.occ.fragment([volTags[0]], [volTags[1]])
```

and look at the mesh (especially of Volume 2) in the GUI. You will see that the meshes of both volumes do not match at their interface in this case.

Comment: Yep I ended up doing something like this, but in lieu of directly calling `fragment`, I call `occ.removeAllDuplicates()` once before final meshing. This makes `get_coord_label` redundant (I can safely create many coinciding/identical entities, and they'll be made unique later), but requires I recreate all my physical groups thereafter. With this comment, I think your answer is sufficiently complete